# Matlab - Multiple Plots in one Figure

Tags: matlab, plot, scroll, uicontrol

I have a question about plots and subplots. I am iterating over some data and I am trying to get everything into a plot. It worked that every plot got written into one plot with `hold on` and `figure` but now I have to fit in regression lines. Therefore I want to plot everythiong into one figure but into different plots. This doesnt work as my plot looks a little bit weird.

[image]

My problem now is, that I cant find real helpful things on how to manage those plots other than using uicontrol. But I have never ever used uicontrol and I can´t find enogh documentation to use it properly. I found this code:

```
figure(1)
panel1 = uipanel('Parent',1);
panel2 = uipanel('Parent',panel1);
set(panel1,'Position',[0 0 .99 1]);
set(panel2,'Position',[-1 0 2 1]);
set(gca,'Parent',panel2);
h = image;    % <- Code for my own image goes here 
s = uicontrol('Style','Slider','Parent',1,...
    'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 .025],...
    'Value',1,'Callback',{@slider_callback1,panel2});
```

but all I get is a callback Problem. I dont know how to switch from a horizontal to a vertikal scrollbar and how to get my plots in there. The code manage it to write into the figure but in a very strange way that results in a similiar way as the subplotting everything.

I hope you can help me as good as always!

PS: This is my current code thats working (picture of the plot after it)

```
%% Clear Workspace

clc, clear all, close all; %

S = {} ;

F = [] ;

figure, hold on ;


%% Specify working directory
myFolder = '/home/k/karkarov92/Documents/Daten Igor/Zwick';
% Check to make sure that folder actually exists.  Warn user if it doesn't.
if ~isfolder(myFolder)
    errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s\nPlease specify a new folder.', myFolder);
    uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
    myFolder = uigetdir(); % Ask for a new one.
    if myFolder == 0
         % User clicked Cancel
         return;
    end
end


%% Start Import from Mathilda aka. Z20

% Get a list of all files in the folder with the desired file name pattern.
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.TXT'); % Change to whatever pattern needed.
theFiles = dir(filePattern);
for k = 1 : length(theFiles)
    baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(theFiles(k).folder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    
    str = baseFileName;
    level = wildcardPattern + "NIE_TOM_1_" ;     % Name of the Pattern before the Name of the Sample
    pat = asManyOfPattern(level);
    str = extractAfter(str,pat);
    Sample = erase(str,".TXT");
    disp(Sample)
    
    delimiterIn = ' ';                           %Extract thickness out of headers
    headerlinesIn = 9;
    G = importdata(fullFileName,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
    G(3);
    H = split(G(3));
    K = H(2);
    thickness = str2double(K)/100 ;
    
    



    
    %read Table and extract Units
    A = readtable(fullFileName,'decimal', ',');      % without decimal and "," data import not with the right value wrong unit
    Units = A(1,:);
    A(1,:) = [];        %units extracted and then stripped from table
    %table = A(1:4,:);  table output test
    
    
    
    B = table2array(A);                     %change data from table to array
    %disp(B(1:4,:)) ;                       %Array output test
    

    
    
    strain = (B(:,2)- B(1,2)) / B(1,2);             %strain calculated and stored in vector strain

    
    stretch = strain +1 ;                           %stretch calculated and stored in vector strain

    crossSection = 5. * thickness ;                 %calculate cauchy stress and cross section 
    cauchyStress = ((B(1:end,3).*stretch) / crossSection ) * 1000 ;   %[GPa]
    
    
    
    
    
    
    M = max(B) ;                                    %exctract maxForce
    maxForce = M(1,3) ;
    
    
    
    
    
    F(end+1) = maxForce ;
    S{k} = Sample ;
    
    
    
 
    
    
    
    plot(stretch,cauchyStress)
    xlabel('Stretch')
    ylabel('Cauchy Stress')
    
    title('Linear Regression for Modulus')


    grid on
    


    
end
```

[image]

Comment: It is a little unclear exactly what you are trying to do.  Have you looked at the `subplot` function to see if it can do what you need?  The ability to customize things there should be more suited to your needs than the panel functionality.

Comment: What's your desired output? What are you trying to achieve with the uicontrol?

Comment: I am trying to see all plots. Because  I want to fit regression lines and add other things i cant use only one plot, because that would look confusing. 

I want to split up those plots into seperate ones so that everything is clear to see. 
Subplot wont work because the figure cant be scrolled through so my space is limited. thats why 49 Plots are cramped together in one picture. 

I found out that by using a GUI with a scrollbar that should be possible. But I couldn´t find enough info to use the GUI and uicontrol properly.

Comment: Ok that makes a little more sense now.  Do you need to go back and forth between the plots?  Since you would only have a few on the screen at a time with the scrollbar anyway, you could just plot a few with subplots, and have it wait for a keypress while you review before updating to the next set of plots, etc.  If you are feeling fancier and did want to go the GUI route, you could include sliders/boxes/etc. to select which plots are displayed and scroll through them in a more controlled fashion

Comment: I dont need to scroll through all of the plots. If I could choose which plot gets displayed with ah dropdown menu or so would be a great help. 
Can you help me with that?